# ExpressJS nested route with param validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i want to perform some validation and addition to the request on specific parameter for a route and all nested routes.

My REST structure is /room/:room/messages

In my main.js

```
const roomRoute = require('roomroute.js');
const messageRoute = require('messageroute.js');
app.use('/room',roomRoute);
app.use('/room/:room/messages',messageRoute);
```

in roomroute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.param('room', function (req,res,next,id) {
    // Just for demo
    var room = {
        id: id,
        title: 'Testroom'
    };
    req.room = room;
    next();
});

router.get('/:room, function (req,res) {
    // Display room to console
    console.log(req.room);
    res.sendStatus(200).end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

In messageroute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams:true });
router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.room); // Not working
});

module.exports = router;
```

When i do a get to a room eg. /room/1234 then req.room is displayed to the console, which actually is want i want.

But when i do a get to eg. /room/1234/messages the route.param('room'... of the parent is not executed, but instead just the get of the messageroute.js.

Is there a way to achieve that the param is evaluated for the parent route and also for all nested routes ?

Thank you,
Stefan

Comment: Is the code above the full code from both `roomroute` and `messageroute`?

Comment: i shortened it a little bit. leaving out const express = require('express') and the module.exports = router. Besides that it is the full code, yes.

Comment: Cool, FWIW best to include full code as my immediate thoughts were you forgot to export the routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a misunderstanding of how nested routers work. In your example you seem to be looking to share a param across `roomroute` and `messageroute`, however, both of those routers have no relation to eachother.

Routers become nested when they're supplied as middleware to another router - you have an example of this already....`app` is a router in itself and you nest both `roomroute` and `messageroute` into it. So based on your current setup, if you want to share `param('room')` across both these routes you will need to configure it at `app` level i.e.

**main.js**

```
const roomRoute = require('roomroute.js');
const messageRoute = require('messageroute.js');

app.param('room', function (req,res,next,id) {
    // Just for demo
    var room = {
        id: id,
        title: 'Testroom'
    };
    req.room = room;
    next();
});
app.use('/room', roomRoute);
app.use('/room/:room/messages', messageRoute);
```

**roomroute.js**

```
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
router.get('/:room', ...);
```

**messageroute.js**

```
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
router.get('/', ...);
```

Comment: Thank you very much James !